# vuelidate in vue Property "$v" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am building a vue component containing form in an html file.
Need to validate form using vuelidate library.

Below warning is showing and validation is not working.

> [Vue warn]: Property "$v" was accessed during render but is not
> defined on instance.    at

```js
const { required, minValue, minLength, email } = window.validators;
    const {Vuelidate} = window.vuelidate;
    const vue = {
        template:
        /*html*/
        `<div>
            <form >
                <p>
                    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" />
                    <span>{{$v}}</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input name="password" v-model="password.password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                    <span></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input name="confirmPassword" v-model="password.confirm" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                    <span></span>
                </p>
                <button @click="submitForm">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        `,
        data() {
            return {
                email: '',
                password: {
                    password: '',
                    confirm: '',
                },
            };
            
        },
        validations:  {
                email: { required },
                password: {
                    password: { required },
                    confirm: { required },
                }
        },
        mounted: function() { 
            
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm() {
                console.log(this.$v)
                alert("Form successfully submitted");
            },
        },
        };
    const app = Vue.createApp(vue);
    app.mount('#app');
    app.use(window.vuelidate.default);
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #F99;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <title></title>

   <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

   <div class="row">

       <div id = "app">


       </div>

   </div>

</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuelidate@0.7.7/dist/vuelidate.min.js" integrity="sha256-La6WkedSRP9RsZaBVOO1mwpob2EhzoiYSCxmAizHsYM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuelidate@0.7.7/dist/validators.min.js" integrity="sha256-0IEcyUDILTKDOFvs84hM79AdpmIDFw1d99udusXv2vQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Vue is working fine but vuelidate is not working.
I have a specific usecase where we want to integrate vuejs in html project.
Vue seems to be a suitable option .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't validate email with Vuelidate in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945380/cant-validate-email-with-vuelidate-in-vue3)

Comment: The package you're trying to use does not have a browser compatible export. One option is to wrap a package yourself, with either webpack or rollup (among other options), using [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve) or node-resolve in webpack), which would include all the required dependencies in your package and re-export `useVuelidate`. Another option is to ask the maintainers of `@vuelidate` to do this themselves and wait. Another is not to use `@vueildate`. Or you can switch to Vue SPA (with vite or @vue/cli).

Comment: can you share any useful link to wrap and export manually so that I can use useVuelidate by adding script tag in html file.

Comment: I've wrapped the steps, undeleted my initial answer and updated it. Should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuelidate does not seem to have an `iife` export. Which means (afaict) that it's not usable in browser, from cdn link. It has to be compiled by a node app, which has to resolve its dependencies.

---

Here's how to re-export as immediately invoked function expression (`iife`) using rollup:

1. Create a temp folder, switch to it and initiate a node project:

```shell
mkdir test && cd test && npm init --yes
```

**Note:** if runing this in a windows command prompt or powershell replace  `&&` with `;` (or simply run each command separately).

2. create `index.js`:

```js
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core';
window.useVuelidate = useVuelidate;
```

3. Add required packages for your export:

```shell
npm i rollup @rollup/plugin-node-resolve @vuelidate/core vue-demi
```

- `rollup` bundles your file,
- node-resolve rollup plugin resolves dependencies and includes them in the bundle
- `vue-demi` is a `@vuelidate/core` dependency.
  In turn, `vue-demi` has `vue` as dependency, but we'll let rollup know via config `vue` is already available in the global scope, so it shouldn't be included in the bundle.

4. create `rollup.config.js`:

```js
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: './index.js',
  output: {
    format: 'iife',
    file: 'vuelidate.iife.js',
    globals: { vue: 'window.Vue' }
  },
  plugins: [nodeResolve()]
}
```

5. Bundle your file:

```shell
./node_modules/.bin/rollup --config rollup.config.js
```

6. If everything went well, you should now have a `vuelidate.iife.js` file in the same folder.
7. Load the file in your browser, after Vue,  (it expects `Vue` to be defined in `globalThis` - a.k.a: `window`).

See it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mirzakhani-tq46j?file=/index.html

Comment: I have searched '@vuelidate/core' script tag but no luck. Is there any '@vuelidate/core' html script tag available compatible with vue3 ? Can you share that. I can not use import on javascript as this is not a node project.

Comment: I've detailed my answer with how to make it available in browser.

Comment: Thank you , This solve my query.